# How to query to get Table-Content by wiki api

Tags: jquery, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get "Table" content of a page by wiki api query:

[image]

the "Table-Content" is block content numbered as 3

I tried this query, but it doesn't work

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&rvprop=content&rvlimit=10&rvparse=1&rvsection=1&rvsection=2&titles=Ha%20Noi&redirects=

BTW, How can I get 2 very first section, instead of only one section with query like this
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the table of contents, or, in other words, the list of sections of a page, you can use [`action=parse&prop=sections`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=Ha%20Noi&redirects

Comment: what can I do if I want to get contents from section 4?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get contents from a specific section you have to add `&section=4` , like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=Ha%20Noi&redirects&section=4
```

Comment: i'm able to get section details from above api by passing section index. but it returning html text . I want to get only plain text. how can i get it ?

Comment: You can get the result in format json or format xml. Not plain text as described in [official wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats)